# .htaccess url rewrite from http to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have just recently updated our site with an SSL certificate. We are rewriting the URL, and when typing in http://example.com or http://www.example.com this gets translated to https://example.com

However we are finding that a lot of visitors have favorites that link to a specific page or file and the .htaccess translate is failing.

for example when clicking on the favorite 
http://example.com/themes/default/images/emailLogo.png
the visitor is then directed to 
https://example.comthemes/default/images/emailLogo.png (notice the missing slash in the URL)

here is my .htaccess file info

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^images/.+$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(example\.org|example-me.org|example.me)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.org/$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^http://example.org/images/(.*) https://example.org/images/$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^http://www.example.org/images/(.*) https://example.org/images/$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /bootstrap.php?file=$1.html [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.phtml$ /bootstrap.php?file=$1.html [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem if anyone else stumbles across this post. 
there was a redirect in the apache config that redirected all port 80 requests to 
https://example.com

I changed this to https://example.com/

(* notice the trailing slash *)